# Text List does not shows up in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm very new to React Native. I'm trying to make a list of items. After typing the code, the app runs with the page name at the top but the page itself is blank. It does not display my text list. Any help is very appreciated.

```
function Home() {
  const FlatListBasics = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.text}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Dan'},
            {key: 'Dominic'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

**Style**

```
text: {
  flex: 1,
  paddingTop: 22
 },
 item: {
   padding: 10,
   fontSize: 18,
   height: 44,
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home component is not returning anything because you created another function within the Home component that returns the flatlist instead of the home component returning the flatlist. There is no need to make a function within the component to return the flatlist. You can either remove the FlatListBasics or make the Home component return the FlatListBasics which is the recommended way.

**Method 1**

```
function Home() {
  const FlatListBasics = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.text}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Dan'},
            {key: 'Dominic'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  
  }
    return <FlatListBasics/>
}
```

**Method 2(Recommended way)**

```
function Home() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.text}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Dan'},
            {key: 'Dominic'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    )
}
```